# Bind label value to MaxLenght of TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, aspxgridview

Is there any way to `bind` value of the "ObjectLenghtValue" Label to the `MaxLength` value of TextBox with id "ObjectValue"???

I have a column in the database that has values that need to bind to `MaxLength` values of ObjectValue `TextBox`?

Maybe it can be done with `jQuery`?

Thanks in advance!

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMyObjects" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" CssClass="GridView" AutoPostBack="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>

                            <button class="myBtn" id="Button1" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  runat="server" ><span>Select</span></button>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ObjectID" runat="server"   margin-Left="100px"  ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ObjectName" runat="server" margin-Left="100px" '></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ObjectValue" runat="server" margin-Left="100px" MaxLength='<%# Bind("Something") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="ObjectLenghtValue" runat="server" margin-Left="100px" ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>    
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What is the difference between this question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438115/handling-null-from-database-to-gridview)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling NULL from database to GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438115/handling-null-from-database-to-gridview)

Comment: Previouse question is about NULL, this is about taken value of a column a binding it to maxlenght ??? Nothings the same.

Comment: Assuming ObjectLenghtValue contains the value then change `Bind("Something")` into `Bind("ObjectLenghtValue")`.